# Grunt stops after running one task with protractor webdriver-manager

Tags: node.js, selenium, gruntjs, npm, protractor

I'm currently trying to tie some Protractor E2E tests into grunt.  So far, not so successful.  All documents I've been able to find say that grunt should work well for my situation.  However, after running the `webdriver-manager update --standalone`, grunt exits without error message or running any other tasks.

my Gruntfile:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    protractor: {
      options: {
        configFile: "./conf.js", // Default config file 
        keepAlive: true, // If false, the grunt process stops when the test fails. 
        noColor: false, // If true, protractor will not use colors in its output. 
        args: {
          // Arguments passed to the command 
        }
      },
      all: {}   // Grunt requires at least one target to run so you can simply put 'all: {}' here too. 
    },

    protractor_webdriver: {

    update : {
        options: {
          path:'node_modules/.bin/',
          command: ['webdriver-manager update --standalone']
        },
      },
      e2eStart: {
        options: {
          keepAlive: true,
          path:'node_modules/.bin/',
          command: ['webdriver-manager start']
        },
      },
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['protractor_webdriver:update', 'protractor_webdriver:e2eStart', 'protractor:all']);
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-protractor-webdriver');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-protractor-runner');


};
```

Because someone may be curious: packages.json

```
{
  "name": "Protractor-me",
  "description": "Protractor-me!",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-protractor-runner": "~2.0.0",
    "grunt-protractor-webdriver": "~0.2.0",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "install": {}
}
```

And lastly, grunt --verbose output

```
$ grunt --verbose
Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.
Reading package.json...OK
Parsing package.json...OK
Initializing config...OK

Registering "grunt-protractor-webdriver" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/brianalbright/workspace/qa/personal/Brian/Angular/feed_editor_2/node_modules/grunt-protractor-webdriver/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/brianalbright/workspace/qa/personal/Brian/Angular/feed_editor_2/node_modules/grunt-protractor-webdriver/package.json...OK
Loading "protractor_webdriver.js" tasks...OK
+ protractor_webdriver

Registering "grunt-protractor-runner" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/brianalbright/workspace/qa/personal/Brian/Angular/feed_editor_2/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/brianalbright/workspace/qa/personal/Brian/Angular/feed_editor_2/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/package.json...OK
Loading "protractor_runner.js" tasks...OK
+ protractor
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ default

No tasks specified, running default tasks.
Running tasks: default

Running "default" task

Running "protractor_webdriver:update" (protractor_webdriver) task
Verifying property protractor_webdriver.update exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: path="node_modules/.bin/", command=["webdriver-manager update --standalone"], keepAlive=false
Starting Selenium server
>> selenium standalone is up to date.

>> chromedriver is up to date.

$
```

It runs the webdriver-manager update, then stops.  It's my understanding that each task should run in order, and not stop until it either ends or errors.  I'm out of ideas!

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a custom task that calls your multiple tasks, like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('foo', 'My "foo" task.', function() {
// Enqueue "bar" and "baz" tasks, to run after "foo" finishes, in-order.
grunt.task.run('bar', 'baz');
// Or:
grunt.task.run(['bar', 'baz']);
});
```

http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#custom-tasks